# Define length and scale picture

Tags: software-rec, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Is there any program under linux where I can do the following:

Suppose I have for example a scan of a drawing on a squared paper and suppose that the squares of the original paper have any distance but not 0,5 cm.

Now I want that the squares of the output picture have a distance of exactly 0.5 cm.

I tried to include the picture to `inkscape` and use the ruler to rezize the picture appropriately but this was a pain.

I think something like this would be great: Have a "distance tool" where you can select two points of a picture (for example two vertices of my squared paper squares) then you define that the distance between those points should be say 0.5 cm then the whole picture should scale appropriately while preserving aspect ratios.

Note that I am mainly interested in a solution where I don't have to measure the distance on the original paper using a physical ruler or something like that.

**Edit**
Finally I want a DIN A4 `pdf` including my picture and print it. In my example the point is that the distance of the squares should be 0.5 cm in the **printed** version...

Comment: i think you will save yourself huge headaches if you start thinking in terms of DPI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch).

Comment: @ixtmixilix Does this help if I don't want to use a physical ruler for the original paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer starts where *ixtmixilix* comment ends and assumes that you have installed `ImageMagick`.

To get a pdf with the right resolution/density you need the margin/squares in Pixels, call it `p`. You can get this via `gimp`, `inkscape`, any other reasonable image editor/viewer or indirectly by the `dpi` of the used scanner multiplied by the real distance in `inch`.

If you want the new margin to be `x`cm's the formula for the resolution/density is

```
r = p / x
```

To build the pdf you have to invoke

```
convert <your_picture> -density <r> -units PixelsPerCentimeter \
<your_pdfs_basename>.pdf
```

Now you can print the pdf or embed the generated pdf in a latex document, etc.  The previously adjusted resolution remains.

Comment: Just for completness: In `gimp` one can use the [Measure Tool](http://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/gimp-tool-measure.html), in inkscape I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks this works if I choose `pdf` as output format for the convert command as you suggested. Since I have to embed the result somewhere else to generate the final pdf I just tested do use `png` as output format and embed it in inkscape. However this doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: I found out that this is actually discussed on the inkscape bug tracker under the title [png resolution not imported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/165952). It seems that several workarounds exists and a patch. Maybe you can find there further hints.

Comment: Is it also possible to modify the convert command to get the picture centered in an A4 pdf (without quality loss)

Comment: I don't know but you can adjust this via the standard gtk printer dialog.

Comment: Thanks. However in the gtk dialogue I can center it only together with auto-rotating

Comment: Ok, I just did `lpr -P myprinter -o position=center mypdf.pdf` this worked as espected.